# Can you use the Nested Interval Property to find the minimum of a set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C \subseteq [0, 1]$ be uncountable.

I'm not sure if the following argument to find the minimum of $C$ using the Nested Interval Property is correct.

Let $I_1 = [0,1]$. Divide $I_1$ into two closed intervals, $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. If the left half contains an element in $C$, let $I_2$ be the left half. Otherwise, let $I_2$ be the right half. Keep repeating this process. In general, construct $I_n$ by dividing $I_{n-1}$ into two closed halves. If the left half contains an element of $C$, let $I_n$ be the left half. Otherwise, let $I_n$ be the right half.

Because C is not empty, this process creates an infinite nested sequence of closed intervals with at least 1 element of $C$ in each interval. By the Nested Interval Property, we know that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n \neq \emptyset$. Finally, because each $I_{n+1}$ is half the length of $I_n$, we know that any two points cannot be in $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$. Therefore, $x = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = $ minimum of $C$.

Comment: try this procedure for $I_1=(0,1]\subseteq [0,1]$. do you get a minimum? is there a minimum at all? your construction gives a slightly different value...

Comment: This proof isn't correct.  You've shown that each $I_n$ contains *some* element of $C$ (indeed, you can construct nested $I_n$ that contain uncountably many elements of $C$), but you haven't shown that there's any point in *all* of the $I_n$.  Try your construction on the (countable) set $\{ 2^{-n} \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ and you'll see what I mean.  That's not surprising.  If $C=(0, 1)$, it's uncountable but never achieves its minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof isn't correct.  You've shown that each $I_n$ contains *some* element of $C$ (indeed, you can construct nested $I_n$ that contain uncountably many elements of $C$), but you haven't shown that there's any point in *all* of the $I_n$.  Try your construction on the (countable) set $\{ 2^{-n} \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ and you'll see what I mean.

That's not surprising.  If $C=(0, 1)$, it's uncountable but never achieves its minimum.  This counterexample demonstrates that even an uncountable subset need not have a minimum (as opposed to a greatest lower bound) in $[0, 1]$.